# windows authentication in programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication

I have hosted 2 website sites Webiste1 and Website2 both secured using integrated windows authentication in IIS. User logged into both site using their windows credentials.

Now I given new link for access website1 to website2 and using response.redirect(URL) for call website2,   I want to allow a user logged into website1 to access website2 using single login.

In other words. I would like all users of website1 have automatic access to website, Is it any way to set windows credentials in programmatically?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: As per ur requirement u have to use passport authentication or make ur database common for two websites.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this out of the box by using a shared web.config across the two IIS instances; which would mean you'd only have one place for your authorization settings. However, I am not sure what the implications of this would be for two different sites.

Authentication cookies across integrated windows sites are passed automatically, so would require no further configuration.

See here for shared config:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/shared-configuration_264